# Python caesar cipher A-Z capital only

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, caesar-cipher

Just need a suggest for my code as, I have my code at the moment so that it will work and just add 5 to the ASCII value, but what I need to know is how can I make this work for just moving 5 places along the alphabet e.g. now if I were to type Z I would just get a _ when I would like to get a D.

### Ceaser Cipher

```
bLoopProgram = True 
while bLoopProgram == True: 

    sEncryptOrDecrypt = input("Encrypt Or Decrypt : ").lower() 
    if sEncryptOrDecrypt == "encrypt": 

        while sEncryptOrDecrypt == "encrypt": 

            sPassNonEnc = input("Enter a password to encrypt : ") 
            aPass = [] 
            for i in range(0, len(sPassNonEnc)): 

                nASCII_VALUE = ord(sPassNonEnc[i]) 

                if nASCII_VALUE < 64: 

                    nASCII_VALUE += 10 

                    aPass.append(chr(nASCII_VALUE)) 

                elif nASCII_VALUE > 63: 

                    nASCII_VALUE -= 10 

                    aPass.append(chr(nASCII_VALUE)) 

                else:
                    print("\n * Unknown Character [ASCII INDEX]")

                    aPass.append()

            print("".join(aPass))

            sSaveToTxt = input("Would you like to save your encrypted password to a text document?\nThe Text document will be found next to this python file and called password_enc (Yes/no): ").lower()
            if sSaveToTxt == "yes":
                fFileRequestedOpen = open('password_enc.txt', 'w')
                fFileRequestedOpen.write("".join(aPass))
                fFileRequestedOpen.close()
                print("Saved to text document have a nice day!")
                break

            elif sSaveToTxt == "no":
                print("okay have a nice day!")
                break

            else:
                print("\n*Invalid Option*\n")


    if sEncryptOrDecrypt == "decrypt":

        while sEncryptOrDecrypt == "decrypt":
            sReadOrInput = input("Would you like to load password from text document if saved,\n or would you like to input a encypted password (read/enter): ").lower()
            if sReadOrInput == "read":               
                fFileRequestedOpen = open('password_enc.txt', 'r')
                sPassEnc = fFileRequestedOpen.read()
                fFileRequestedOpen.close()
                aPass = []
                for i in range(0, len(sPassEnc)):

                    nASCII_VALUE = ord(sPassEnc[i])

                    if nASCII_VALUE < 64:

                        nASCII_VALUE -= 10

                        aPass.append(chr(nASCII_VALUE))

                    elif nASCII_VALUE > 63:

                        nASCII_VALUE += 10

                        aPass.append(chr(nASCII_VALUE))

                    else:
                        print("\n * Unknown Character [ASCII INDEX]")

                print("".join(aPass))
                break
            if sReadOrInput == "enter":
                sPassEnc = input("Enter a password to decrypt : ")
                aPass = []
                for i in range(0, len(sPassEnc)):

                    nASCII_VALUE = ord(sPassEnc[i])

                    if nASCII_VALUE < 64:

                        nASCII_VALUE -= 10

                        aPass.append(chr(nASCII_VALUE))

                    elif nASCII_VALUE > 63:

                        nASCII_VALUE += 10

                        aPass.append(chr(nASCII_VALUE))

                    else:
                        print("\n * Unknown Character [ASCII INDEX]")

                print("The now unencrypted password is:")
                print("".join(aPass))
                break

    elif sEncryptOrDecrypt == "quit":
        quit()

    else:
        print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use modulo (%) to restrict your values within 65 (A) and 90 (Z)

For instance:

```
nASCII_VALUE = 90  # This is a Z
nASCII_VALUE += 5  # chr(95) = _
print(chr(((nASCII_VALUE - 64) % 26) + 64))
```

This will print 'E' (5th letter of alphabeth)